# Can you remove metadata from already sent photos

Tags: iphone, metadata, exif

Is there any way to remove the location from photos already texted to someone via iMessage?

Comment: That is built into the Camera settings, if you haven't turn off the Geolocation beforehand, then there is nothing you can do about the sent picture except delete it and retake it with geolocation turned off.

Answer (score 3):

No.

Once they have it, what they have is a completely separate copy, entirely in their control.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible to edit any message once it has been sent with iMessage, photos included.